# How can i mock angular-auth-oidc client to return fake data

Tags: typescript, angular6, karma-jasmine, auth0, angular-auth-oidc-client

How can i mock angular-auth-oidc-client to return some fake token using karma-jasmine. Below is the code that i need to write a unit test case.

```
getToken() {
    return this.oidcSecurityService.getToken();
}
```

Comment: Did my answer worked for ur question ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek it worked for me Vivek. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is my article which covers all such basic testing scenarios](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7) to start with. [There is another article which specifically talks about this case](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49).  Feel free to provide your feedback

You'll need to create a `stub` which will mock the behavior of `oidcSecurityService`,

```
export class OidcSecurityServiceStub{
   getToken(){
      return 'some_token_eVbnasdQ324';
   }
   // similarly mock other methods "oidcSecurityService" as per the component requirement

}
```

then in `spec` file, use `useClass` as below in `TestBed`:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ WhateverComponent],
     providers:    [ {provide: OidcSecurityService(or whatever the name is), useClass: OidcSecurityServiceStub} ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're testing a component.
You could try the method mentioned here:
https://angular.io/guide/testing#final-setup-and-tests.

Edit and excerpt from the site:

```
let userServiceStub: Partial<UserService>;

beforeEach(() => {
  // stub UserService for test purposes
  userServiceStub = {
    isLoggedIn: true,
    user: { name: 'Test User'}
  };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ],
     providers:    [ {provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceStub } ]
  });

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
  comp    = fixture.componentInstance;

  // UserService from the root injector
  userService = TestBed.get(UserService);

  //  get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
  el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.welcome');
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23624231)

Comment: Hi I updated my answer with the code. Could you verify it meets the standards please? Thanks.

Comment: @Eli : The answer you have provided is not exactly what the user has asked.  Its really great that u are improving it. You can refer my answer. Your answer has more code with not much attention to exact thing required. Please take my suggestions as a friend and not as a critic to grow on Stackoverflow :) . Cheers mate !